# Compatible pdf manipulator with current android version (8.1)

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin

I am working on a android application that needs to generate a .pdf by information inserted in the app by filling an existing .pdf form.
What can i use that works with xamarin current android versions

i tried Itextsharp, Itext 7 and PDF Box but they are all outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a built in PDF generating class. See: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument

A typical use of the APIs looks like this [ported to C#]:

```
        // create a new document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // crate a page description
        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(100, 100, 1).Create();

        // start a page
        Page page = document.StartPage(pageInfo);

        // draw something on the page
        View content = FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        content.Draw(page.Canvas);

        // finish the page
        document.FinishPage(page);
        // add more pages
        // write the document content
        FileStream fileOutputStream = new FileStream(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), FileMode.CreateNew);
        document.WriteTo(fileOutputStream);

        // close the document
        document.Close();
```